# why angular5 compiler stop generating .ts ngFactory files but .js ngFactory files instead?

Tags: angular

Since angular5, when doing AOT compilation, angular compiler will generate js ngFactory files, but in early versions (from 2 to 4), angular compiler generates ts ngFactory files. 
I am wondering why this change happens..

Comment: I'm not aware of this, but what differences does it make tho? `TS` compiles down to `JS` anyways.

Comment: to reduce the build bundle size